# how to grab JSON Data from url using JavaScript? (new to JSON)

Tags: javascript, json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>JavaScript - read JSON from URL</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
function setup() {
 loadJSON("https://www.westelm.com/services/catalog/v4/category/shop/new/all-new/index.json", gotData, 'jsonp');

}

function gotData(data){
    alert(data);

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I am new to the developer role, please help.  First it kept giving me Access denial to the url ERROR!. Then i learned about jsonp and added it. Now i don't see anything showing up, when i should be getting the json data. !JSON data from the url is correct ran it in JSONLINT!

Comment: JSONP needs to be supported by the server. If it doesn't support it you cannot use it.

Comment: how would i go about making the server support jsonp?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://www.westelm.com/services/catalog/v4/category/shop/new/all-new/index.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

That code will normally work, but for this you should be getting this error:

```
Failed to load     
https://www.westelm.com/services/catalog/v4/category/shop/new/all- 
new/index.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on 
the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

That's because this server doesn't allow JSON Reqs, and will not allow you access. You could try using CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) but I'm not sure how much that will help you

Comment: it gave me that error you mentioned and CORS did not help.

Comment: @Ar8itrator I know, I'm saying you can't fix it. You don't have anything you can do.

Comment: Unless you have power over that server

Comment: Instead of calling third party url from JS, you can write code in your application and call your service, which indirectly call the above url using server to html code, like in html parser.

Comment: @Ar8itrator Please mark this the correct answer if it helped

Comment: @SheshankShankar i wish i could, but it did not help me. I am still stuck.

Comment: @Ar8itratorI I see, but there is no way to do this.

Comment: @SheshankS. "there is always a way!" once i figure this out ill post it up here, i appreciate your help. thank you